# How can I send xml variable by select's option value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var services = $(result).find("root>content>root");
services.each(function () {
  var r = $(this);
  var name = r.find('service').attr("name");
  $('#service_select').append('<option value="'+ r +'">' + name + '</option>');
}
```

var **r** contains:

```
    <root>
      <service name="" status="" .. ></service>
    </root>
```

when select changes, I wanted to get that xml

```
$(document).on('change', '#service_select', function ()  {
    var selected = $('#service_select').val();
    var name = selected.find('service').attr("name");

    console.dirxml(selected);    
});
```

I can't get values from variable selected. In console I get [object Object]. How to get xml format instead?

Comment: I guess you need to parse the XML using [.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the XML using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) parseXML utility.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( r ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  name = $xml.find( "service" ).attr("name");
```

Comment: var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(r[0]);

Comment: talking with myself :)